# Is it possible to display multiple partial view one below row-wise in single _Layout.cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview, html-renderer

I have a situation where i wish to render 2 partial views in single layout.cshtml one below another. Each partial view belongs to separate controller. I processed it using 2 different approach, the first one which i wanted it to work didn't worked out.
What i wanted it is to have partial view controller of categoris1 (see div-id below in layout.cshtml) and then below it display partial view of categoris2 div.

let's say this is my _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - ABCD</title>

    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                @Html.ActionLink("TitleName", "Index", "Files", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row panel">

      //My first view should be displayed here
        <div id="categoris1" class="col-lg-3">
            @Html.Action("DispatchedProducts", "DispatchedProducts")
        </div>

      //Second view should be displayed here just below first one
       <div id="categoris2" class="col-lg-3">
            @Html.Action("DisplayUnDispatchedProducts", "UnDispatchedProducts")
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-8">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My MVC Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This results in displaying of the categoris1 div controller view only when i run application (but not categoris2 partialview)and categoris2 div partial view is displayed at other url (when i write path to controller and view in browser) and what i wanted it is to display on same page just below categoris1 .

My next approach which worked was i just kept this categoris2 div (line below) in the partial view of '`DispatchedProducts`' at the bottom of `DisplayDispatchedProducts.cshtml` and **it displayed exactly what i expected.**

```
<div id="categoris2" class="col-lg-3">
   @Html.Action("DisplayUnDispatchedProducts", "UnDispatchedProducts")
 </div>
```

Complete DisplayDispatchedProducts.cshtml something like this:

```
@model  IList<ABC.Models.Product>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "First view";
}

<div class="col-md-10">
    <h2>Dispatched Items</h2>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Dispatched Items</label>
        <table>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tc>
                    <td>
                        <img src=@item.ProdUrl height="100" width="100" />
                    </td>
                </tc>
            }
            <hr />
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

and DisplayDispatchedProducts controller has method like this (similar is other controller and partial view with same return types but different queries) :

```
 public PartialViewResult DisplayDispatchedProducts()
        {
            productDispatched = uow.ProductsRepository.GetProductWithOrder().ToList();
            return PartialView(productDispatched);
        }
```

But i want to move with the first approach to have call to both partial views in just `_Layout.cshtml` file like i mentioned above. Which i expected to display both in a row below each other. Is it feasible to happen ? How to make it work ?

**Please let me know if any other info needed**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling Html.RenderPartial or Html.RenderAction?

- RenderPartial(String partialViewName)
- RenderAction(String actionName, String controllerName, Object routeValue)

There are other overrides for each of these methods depending on which version of the framework you are using.